# Can anyone help me find why do I get two different solutions for the following expression

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

Sorry if I'm a bit dumb today, it seems I Can't find where I went wrong in Solving the following expression in two different ways. Can anyone help?

Solution 1

$$\frac {\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{-3}}=\sqrt{\frac{27}{-3}}=\sqrt{-9}=3i$$

Solution 2

$$\frac {\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{-3}}=
\frac {3\sqrt3}{\sqrt3\sqrt{-1}}=
\frac{3}{i}=-3i$$

Comment: The relation $\sqrt {ab}=\sqrt {a}\times \sqrt b$ only holds for positive real numbers.  The usual "paradox" that arises if you try to extend it to negative reals would be something like $1=\sqrt 1 =\sqrt {-1\times -1}=\sqrt {-1}\times \sqrt {-1}=i^2=-1$.

Comment: I don't think you made a mistake anywhere. Every complex number has two square roots, in this case $3i$ and $-3i$. Both solutions seem equally valid in my opinion.

Comment: Cpiegore's answer works fine for me. Not only does it solve my problem but also seems to dismantle Lulu's paradox.

Comment: lulu didn't give you a paradox. They stated why it is impossible to define a single-valued square root on negative real numbers, much less all of $\Bbb C$, that obeys the same rules we are familiar with from the positives. cpiegore got around this by treating the square root as a "multi-valued function", which is a well-known approach. But "multi-valued" function is an oxymoron, as "function" in part means "single-valued". Having expressions take on multiple values opens a very big can of worms that makes these identities difficult to interpret.